# Am I missing something when someone needs to meet a “fisherman with a bad complexion” in The Uplift War?

Tags: the-uplift-war

In Brin’s *The Uplift War*, Fiben Bolger (the uplifted chimp) goes to (enemy-occupied) Port Helenia to connect with the underground movement there.

He has a garbled message about how to recognize the entity he’s supposed to meet:

> “Fiben was looking for someone dressed as a fisherman…”
>
> “…something about a ‘fisherman with a bad complexion.’”
>
> “He didn’t see anyone who looked like a scar-faced fisherman.”

The message was garbled: He was supposed to recognize Gailet Jones who was acting like a hooker. However, Gailet has no scars and has smooth skin. She has an associate with a scarred face (Max), but he isn’t with Gailet when the meeting occurs.

Is there some pun about bad complexion and prostitutes that I’m missing, or was the message so garbled that it wasn’t clear that the chimp with the scar wouldn’t be visible at the meeting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most likely she passed along the message that he should

> '*look out for a hooker with a scarface*'.

"*Hooker*" became fisherman (e.g. someone who uses a hook professionally) and the scarred face was attributed to them as if they were a single individual.

---

**Evidence**

We know that Max was with her at the rendezvous point, so it's unlikely that the message would have been to look for a single individual.

> *“No it did not! Before you appeared, several solitary chens showed up
> dressed likely enough to make me put on my act. **Poor Max had to stun
> half a dozen of them,** and the alley was starting to get full! But it
> was already too late to change the rendezvous, or the password—”*
>
> *“Which nobody understood! **Hooker? You should have realized something
> like that would get garbled!”***

and we know that he has poor complexion, which lends credence to the idea that part of the message was about him, given that her skin is described as smooth.

> ***The big, scarred chim named Max stood watch nearby**, a captured Gubru laser rifle in one hand. He offered a hand. “You okay, Fiben?”*

---

Since "Old Earth" in this context is the word 20th century word 'hooker', it makes no sense for the other part of the sentence to have been 'pox-ridden' or somesuch.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 17):

Sounds like a bad translation of "poxy whore" -- a "hooker" might come up as "fisherman" while "poxy" originated from the skin lesions caused by advanced syphillis.

To an uplifted chimp in this setting, even the untranslated original wouldn't have made much if any sense, but it's an Old Earth expression from the 17th to 19th century.

Comment: Ah.  That makes sense (note that the message was intended to be between an uplifted chimp and a human professor, both of whom shared an interest in pre-Contact literature (unfortunately the professor had died before the message was received))

Comment: Been a long time since I read the Uplift books, but it sounds like an unforeseen consequence of using another race's smart messaging.

Comment: Consequence of using a coded message that relied on a particular person to be available

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting poxy from. Surely it's more likely that the chimp was told 'hooker with a guy with a scar" and got that garbled?

Comment: @Valorum Given the state of biomedical technology in the setting it’s worth considering that many people (not just the chimp in question) may not have any knowledge of things like disfiguring skin diseases, so the character trying to interpret the response jumping from ‘bad complexion’ to ‘scar-faced’ does make some sense in context. The later explanation about interest in pre-Contact literature makes it pretty clear that the actual message was an ‘old Earth‘ euphemism of some sort, which in turn makes sense because the invaders would have almost no context for understanding it.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn - 'Old Earth' in this context is explicitly stated to be hooker (e.g. Current Earth slang)

Comment: @Valorum Taken in context when it’s explained later in the same book, it’s implied that the whole phrasing is Old Earth slang (though they don’t explicitly state _what_ the specific Old Earth slang that constituted that part of the message was). Additionally, it’s not explicit, but it’s implied that not only the terminology for prostitute, but also the part about ‘a bad complexion’ was mistranslated. Under that assumption that both implications are true, ‘poxy whore’ or some variant thereof is about the only single phrase that happens to fit the translation.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn - It says later in the book that one of the scrambled words was hooker, not whore or doxy. Poxy wouldn't go with either of those in any form of English, modern or otherwise- *"I said I'd pass myself off as a hooker"*

Comment: I've downvoted because I believe this answer to be incorrect. It's well-written and well-argued, but I just don't think that someone using 20th century slang would say that they were passing themselves off as a pox-ridden *hooker*